# SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, bids

This is my first question here and before posting this question I have checked all the previous questions same as these or related to this one but I'm unable to solve the problem despite applying the fixes suggested by other members. Please, help.

My scenario: I have put multiple excel sheets (in MS Excel 2007 format) in a single workbook. I have created a User variable with package scope that holds the first sheet name within a for each loop container.

- What I want to do

: I want to read multiple excel sheets within a single workbook and then write them to a SQL table. I have been able to accomplish reading a single excel file and writing it to a SQL table but not multiple excel files.

- Software installed:

  I'm using SQL Server Enterprise edition R2 with BIDS in it.
- Resolution steps that I have followed so far:

  - Have set the `DelayValidation` property in excel connection manager as `True`
  - Have used a Variable with package level scope and assigned it the first sheet name which in my case is named as 'Sheet1"
  - My connection string is `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +@[User::SheetName]+ ";Extended Properties=\"EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES\";"` which is evaluated as correct
  - Have set the Package property to use 32 bit validation as suggested in this forum as I'm using a 32 bit OS

I get no errors at the design time but when i start debugging the project, I get the following errors given below,

```
[Excel Source [1]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.
[Excel Source [1]] Error: Opening a rowset for "C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\Dataset\BasicData.xlsx" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: "component "Excel Source" (1)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: One or more component failed validation.
Error: There were errors during task validation.
```

Please, can anyone let me know what am i doing wrong and how do I fix these errors.

Thank you,

Comment: Are you looping through the sheets? Provided the tables are the same in each sheet this shouldn't be a problem but instead of setting the sheet in the connection string iirc you set it on the source.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm looping through the sheets using the for each container loop. However, please can you be explain the last part of your answer in detail. I'm unable to understand this part of your answer "instead of setting the sheet in the connection string iirc you set it on the source" and how to implement it

Comment: If by source you mean the 'excel source' then yes in the excel source I have set the sheet path and also in its properties I have defined in OpenRowsetVariable the value User::SheetName

Comment: Does the excel file exist in that location? Is it already open by something/someone else?

Comment: The excel file exists in the specified location, and No its not open by anyone.

Comment: Is there only one source using the file in the dataflow? How are you getting the sheet names? Are all the sheets exactly the same?

Comment: Yes, all the sheets are exactly the same. There is only one excel source in the dataflow (the data flow is encapsualted within a For each loop container) which is connected to a data conversion flow  which is then connected to an OLE DB connection (for SQL). To get the sheet names I am using a user defined variable that has the package scope. If it makes any difference It works with a single excel sheet but not multiple sheets.